# Passing an object with data from one view to another view in Swift using Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass an object with data from one view to another view using Swift4. However, I get this problem when trying to print.
Here is the message that I get:

> 2018-03-21 21:47:03.542578-0400 Sudoku[64427:1070575] <UIView:
>   0x7fd28bc0b4c0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); autoresize = W+H; layer =
>   <CALayer: 0x604000038500>>'s window is not equal to
>   <Sudoku.setupSudoku: 0x7fd28bf256c0>'s view's window!

Here is the picture of my View. Identifier for segue: setupScreen

[image]

Here is the code in setPlayer:

```
class setPlayer: UIViewController {
    var singleUser:playerInfor=playerInfor()
    var randomGame:Int = -1
    var playerName:String=""
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPlayerName: UITextField!
    var sizeOfSudoku:Int = 9 //for project 1, let take one size of sudoku

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Communication-Network-Vector-Illustration.jpg")!)
        self.txtPlayerName.layer.borderWidth=2.0
        self.txtPlayerName.layer.borderColor=UIColor.blue.cgColor
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func randomNumber(){
        self.randomGame=Int(arc4random_uniform(3)+1)
    }

    func initialize(){
        //if(size)

        if txtPlayerName.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
            self.playerName="Player1"
        } else {
            self.playerName=self.txtPlayerName.text!
        }
        self.singleUser=playerInfor(playerName:self.playerName,size:self.sizeOfSudoku,time:0, randomSudoku:self.randomGame)
        //print (self.singleUser.size)
    }

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
        initialize()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupScreen", sender: self.singleUser)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "setupScreen"{
            if let destination=segue.destination as?setupSudoku{
                destination.objectPlayer=sender as?playerInfor
                print(singleUser.playerName)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func size9(_ sender: Any) {
        self.sizeOfSudoku=9
    }

    @IBAction func Size6(_ sender: Any) {
        self.sizeOfSudoku=9
    }
```

Here is playerInfor

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class playerInfor{
    var playerName:String=""
    var size:Int=0
    var time:Int=var randomSudoku:Int=0

    init(playerName:String,size:Int,time:Int,randomSudoku:Int) {
        self.playerName=playerName
        self.size=size
        self.time=time
        self.randomSudoku=randomSudoku
    }
}
```

Here is setupSudoku

```
class setupSudoku: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var stackViewButtons: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var newNumber=0
    var objectPlayer:playerInfor!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.objectPlayer?.time)

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing your issue?

Comment: FYI - Class/struct/enum names should start with uppercase letters. Variable/function/case names start with lowercase letters.

Comment: @maddy, I think it comes from function startButton() and prepare.

Comment: @maddy: I am trying to pass the object with data from setPlayer to setupSudoku. However, I cannot get the values of object in setupSudoku. So it returns the message "2018-03-21 21:47:03.542578-0400 Sudoku[64427:1070575] >'s window is not equal to 's view's window!" when I am trying to print a value in the object

Comment: there is my mistake when copying the code:  var time:Int=var randomSudoku:Int=0 .   It supposes to be: var time:Int =0      var randomSudoku:Int =0.

Comment: You should [edit] your question. Don't post details in comments.

Answer (score 3):

You have setup your segue incorrectly in your storyboard, and it is attempting to segue twice. To confirm this is the case, select your segue in your storyboard and check if your button highlights, like this:

[image: Highlighted button for selected segue]

To resolve, delete this segue and create a new one, by control-dragging from the view controller (not the button) to the destination, like so:

[image: View controller segue dragging]

Make sure to reset the new segues identifier back to `setupScreen`. Then you should be good to go!

Comment: thanks @Jake. I have fixed it as you said. I have a question that since Xcode allow me to drag from a button to a new controller. So when should I drag from a button to a new controller?

Comment: Dragging from the button will cause Xcode to perform the code `performSegue(withIdentifier: <identifier>, sender: <UIButton>)` for you when the button is tapped, with the UIButton tapped as the sender. You would usually use it when there isn't any configuration needed before segueing. eg. you didn't need to call your `initialize()` function, you could remove the whole `@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any)` function altogether. But you already had the code to perform the segue so this was the easier fix.